# "Peter sang a song to Julie", Is "to Julie" is an adjunct or complement?

Tags: syntax, english, grammar, adjuncts, complement

> *Peter sang a song to Julie.*

It seems that the verb "sang" selects the preposition, but to Julie is optional. And if we apply it to an X' Schema, how shall we do it? To Julie is the dependent of sang a song?

Comment: The NP "a song" and the PP "to Julie" are complements (dependents) of "sing", the difference being that the former is a core complement, the latter a non-core one. "Sing", in this sense, selects the prep "to". "Julie" is a semantic argument of the verb in that she is one of the entities involved, and it follows that the PP containing "Julie" together with the governing prep "to" is also a complement of the verb. The whole PP "to Julie" is licensed by "sing", and hence is not an adjunct, such as the locative one in "sing a song in the bath" or the temporal one in "sing a song at tea-time".

Comment: It's probably not the intended meaning of the sentence, but for completeness, I'll point out that "a song to Julie" can stand on its own legs, in which case the sentence would mean that Peter sang a song dedicated to Julie, and then the PP "to Julie" would be a dependent of the NP "a song".

Comment: Hi,BillJ,thank you for your reply. I thought in the same way as you. But I found it is difficult to draw an X' tree, because the compliment is not stackable. If both two parts"a song" and "to Julie" are compliment, it violates the rule. But I'm not sure whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Anything that works for this sentence will work for any 3-place transfer predicate with the Dative Alternation -- _He sang Julie a song/a song to Julie; He gave his book to the library/the library his book; He told Julie the secret/the secret to Julie_, as well as Benefactive mimics -- _He dug Julie a clam/a clam for Julie; He fixed Julie supper/supper for Julie_. The term "Indirect Object" (or "3", the last and least of the core arguments) gets confused with sentences like this.

Comment: I don't do x-bar stuff (I find it unintuitive), so I've no idea why the two-complement analysis violates the rule. Examples abound where a verb has two complements, e.g. "She informed me that she had been insulted", where both "me" and "that she had been insulted" are complement of "inform". I can draw you a 'standard' (i.e. non-x-bar) tree of your example, but I'm not sure it will be of much help.

Comment: Hi, BillJ, thank you for your help. I think to Julie should be an adjunct, because sing is a transitive verb, but inform is a ditransitive verb. That's to say, sing a song can exist independently, but inform a piece of information cannot. Therefore, they are not the same thing.

Comment: Hi, LjL, thanks for your reply. But if so, "the song to Julie" in the sentence" Peter sang a song to Julie" is a NP, which is the same as "the book on the shelf" in the sentence" The boy read the book on the shelf". But they are different, aren't they?

Comment: @ShirleenYoung Yes, it would be. Perhaps you should tell us what meaning you intended when you wrote the sentence.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you very much! At first I wanted  to make sure whether that PP was complement or not.Because I have to draw an x-bar tree to finish my assignment. But now after searching online I think it should be adjunct. Anyway, thanks for your patience and kindness.

Comment: @ShirleenYoung No, it's a complement. Complements express the entities involved in the clause ("Peter" and "Julie"), while adjuncts are concerned with the circumstances of the situation where they express manner, spatial or temporal location, duration, condition, and so on. If you say that the PP "to Julie" is an adjunct in your assignment, you will be marked down, so be careful!